A Pandigital Multiplication
Solve ABCDE x 7 = FGHIJ where, as usual, different letters stand for different digits. No leading zeros.
Please show the full analysis of how these digits can be determined.

Are these digits really determinable without guess and check? I have the answer, but my explanation would boil down to "I messed with it until it worked."

First,

A = 1.

One strategy for restricting the remaining search space starts by

pairing the digits (B,F), (C,G), (D,H). Each pair has only a handful of possibilities based on possible ranges, which we can further narrow by eliminating digits that have already been used. After picking each pair, we can check the remaining possible products for a unique I using different values of E except 0, 5, and anything that makes J reuse a digit.

For example,

if B = 4, because 14000 x 7 = 98000, F must be 9. Then because 14100 x 7 = 98700 and 14200 x 7 = 99400, (C,G) must be (0,8).

Furthermore, we have

14030 x 7 = 9821014040 x 7 = 9828014050 x 7 = 9835014060 x 7 = 9842014070 x 7 = 9849014080 x 7 = 98560

so

(D,H) must be (3,2), (5,3), or (7,5). If we pick (7,5), then only E = 6 gives a unique J = 2, which finally gives a unique I = 3, so 14076 x 7 = 98532 works.

If you really want the full analysis,...

We start with

1BCDE x 7 = FGHIJ → (B,F) = (0,7), (2,8), (2,9), (3,9), or (4,9)

and continue... (warning: turn back!)

 10CDE x 7 = 7GHIJ → (C,G) = (3,2), (4,2), (4,3), (5,3), (5,4), (6,4), (8,5), (8,6), or (9,6)  103DE x 7 = 72HIJ → (D,H) = (5,4), (6,5), or (8,6)   1035E x 7 = 724IJ → E = (none)   1036E x 7 = 725IJ → E = 4    10364 x 7 = 72548 ✗   1038E x 7 = 726IJ → E = (none)  104DE x 7 = 72HIJ → (D,H) = (none)  104DE x 7 = 73HIJ → (D,H) = (5,2) or (6,2)   1045E x 7 = 732IJ → E = 8    10458 x 7 = 73206 ✗   1046E x 7 = 732IJ → E = (none)  105DE x 7 = 73HIJ → (D,H) = (2,6), (4,8), or (6,9)   1052E x 7 = 736IJ → E = 4    10524 x 7 = 73668 ✗   1054E x 7 = 738IJ → E = (none)   1056E x 7 = 739IJ → E = 2 or 4    10562 x 7 = 73934 ✗    10564 x 7 = 73948 ✗  105DE x 7 = 74HIJ → (D,H) = (none)  106DE x 7 = 74HIJ → (D,H) = (2,3) or (9,8)   1062E x 7 = 743IJ → E = (none)   1069E x 7 = 748IJ → E = (none)  108DE x 7 = 75HIJ → (D,H) = (4,9)   1084E x 7 = 759IJ → E = (none)  108DE x 7 = 76HIJ → (D,H) = (9,2)   1089E x 7 = 762IJ → E = (none)  109DE x 7 = 76HIJ → (D,H) = (2,4), (2,5), (3,5), or (4,5)   1092E x 7 = 764IJ → E = (none)   1092E x 7 = 765IJ → E = (none)   1093E x 7 = 765IJ → E = 2 or 4    10932 x 7 = 76524 ✗    10934 x 7 = 76538 ✗   1094E x 7 = 765IJ → E = (none) 12CDE x 7 = 8GHIJ → (C,G) = (0,4), (3,6), (4,6), (4,7), (5,7), or (7,9)  120DE x 7 = 84HIJ → (D,H) = (5,3), (7,5), or (9,6)   1205E x 7 = 843IJ → E = (none)   1207E x 7 = 845IJ → E = 9    12079 x 7 = 84553 ✗   1209E x 7 = 846IJ → E = (none)  123DE x 7 = 86HIJ → (D,H) = (5,4), (7,5), or (9,7)   1235E x 7 = 864IJ → E = (none)   1237E x 7 = 865IJ → E = (none)   1239E x 7 = 867IJ → E = (none)  124DE x 7 = 86HIJ → (D,H) = (none)  124DE x 7 = 87HIJ → (D,H) = (3,0)   1243E x 7 = 870IJ → E = (none)  125DE x 7 = 87HIJ → (D,H) = (6,9)   1256E x 7 = 879IJ → E = (none)  127DE x 7 = 89HIJ → (D,H) = (5,3) or (6,3)   1275E x 7 = 893IJ → E = (none)   1276E x 7 = 893IJ → E = (none) 12CDE x 7 = 9GHIJ → (C,G) = (8,0)  128DE x 7 = 90HIJ → (D,H) = (none) 13CDE x 7 = 9GHIJ → (C,G) = (5,4), (6,5), (7,5), (7,6), (8,6), or (8,7)  135DE x 7 = 94HIJ → (D,H) = (2,6) or (2,7)   1352E x 7 = 946IJ → E = (none)   1352E x 7 = 947IJ → E = (none)  136DE x 7 = 95HIJ → (D,H) = (0,2), (2,4), or (8,7)   1360E x 7 = 952IJ → E = 4    13604 x 7 = 95228 ✗   1362E x 7 = 954IJ → E = (none)   1368E x 7 = 957IJ → E = 2    13682 x 7 = 95774 ✗  137DE x 7 = 95HIJ → (D,H) = (none)  137DE x 7 = 96HIJ → (D,H) = (2,0), (4,2), (5,2), (8,4), or (8,5)   1372E x 7 = 960IJ → E = 4    13724 x 7 = 96068 ✗   1374E x 7 = 962IJ → E = (none)   1375E x 7 = 962IJ → E = 4    13754 x 7 = 96278 ✗   1378E x 7 = 964IJ → E = (none)   1378E x 7 = 965IJ → E = (none)  138DE x 7 = 96HIJ → (D,H) = (2,7)   1382E x 7 = 967IJ → E = (none)  138DE x 7 = 97HIJ → (D,H) = (5,0) or (6,0)   1385E x 7 = 970IJ → E = (none)   1386E x 7 = 970IJ → E = 2    13862 x 7 = 97034 ✗ 14CDE x 7 = 9GHIJ → (C,G) = (0,8)  140DE x 7 = 98HIJ → (D,H) = (3,2), (5,3), or (7,5)   1403E x 7 = 982IJ → E = (none)   1405E x 7 = 983IJ → E = 6    14056 x 7 = 98392 ✗   1407E x 7 = 985IJ → E = 6    14076 x 7 = 98532 ✓


Partial answer:
Taking

 digit sums

of the given equation we get

 2A+2B+2C+2D+2E+F+G+H+I+J = 0 mod 9

we also know that

 A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J = 0 mod 9

and therefore

 A+B+C+D+E is a multiple of 9 as is  F+G+H+I+J

For the r.h.s. to have 5 digits

 A must be 1 and B<5

If B>2 then

 F=9 and A+B+C+D+E <= 1+4+6+7+8 = 26 and therefore A+B+C+D+E <= 18

if B<=2 then

 F=7 or 8 and A+B+C+D+E <= 1+2+6+8+9 = 26 and therefore A+B+C+D+E <= 18

Also,

 A+B+C+D+E >= 0+1+2+3+4 = 10 which leaves only A+B+C+D+E = 18 and F+G+H+I+J = 27

If B=4 then F,G = 9,8 and

 there can be no carry from H into G, forcing C=0 and D,E = 6,7 or D,E = 7,6

The latter gives the solution

 14076x7 = 98532

So far, so painless.
It remains to rule out everything else. Which, unfortunately, I cannot without getting super-tedious.

It is easy to exclude some pairs of (E,J), those remains to be checked: (2,4) (4,8) (6,2) (7,9) (8,6) (9,3).
